# Stripe - how to get balance transactions (credit card fees) from a charge in a Connected account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe. I process credit card payments on behalf of other Stripe accounts using Connect.

Now, I want to fetch credit card processing fees. There is this API endpoint for that:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list

```
\Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all(['source'=> "ch_xxxxxx"]);
```

It works fine for my own Stripe account. However it returns an empty list for any charge made to Connected accounts.

How do I get those credit card charges via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [kind of charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types) are you making on the connected account? The Balance Transactions will only appear as `type=charge` then using "direct charges". If you're using Destination charges, these transactions appear as `type=payment` with `source=py_123`. If you use [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to get the `source` with `expand[]=data.source` (`data.` [because it's a list](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#lists)) you'll find a `source_transfer` ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-source_transfer)) you can use to trace to the original charge on your platform.

Comment: It was a direct charge. You made me realize I failed to pass the account ID of the connected account. Like this: `$transactions = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all(['source'=> 'ch_xxx'], ['stripe_account' => 'acct_xxx']);`